# series combinations

Tags: summation, combinatorics

is there any possibility of displaying all possible series of the form: "1+/-2^2+/-3^2+/-...+/-n^2", where one can choose the sign before the each term and knows the numbers of the terms in the series? (Summing up I would like to find out all possible combinations of the signs.)  I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 6):

For n terms there are $2^{n-1}$ arrangements of signs of terms after first term. If the aim (for small n) is to display some examples of all sign arrangements for n-1 terms after first term then here is a way. There are doubtless much better ways.

```
f[n_?Positive] := 
 With[{t = Tuples[{-1, 1}, n - 1], s = Tuples[{"-", "+"}, n - 1], 
   sq = HoldForm[#^2] & /@ Range[1, n]}, 
  Grid[{#1, Row[{Row@#2, " = ", #3}]} & @@@ 
    Thread[{Range[2^(n - 1)], 
      Riffle[sq, #] & /@ s, (({1}~Join~#).ReleaseHold[sq] & /@ t)}], 
   Frame -> All, BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Kartika", Blue, 12}]]
```

for example:`f[3]`

[image]

or `f[5]`

[image]

If the sign of first term is also included then $2^n$ and code can be simplified.

Comment: You beat me to it, and with a solution that's more elegant than what I was working on, both from the code and from the presentation perspective, so I don't even feel bad about it ;-) (+1)

Comment: @MarcoB thank you for kind words and vote...variety of answers makes this site so enjoyable and instructive :)